# Why does my code run faster in Eclipse console than in Eclipse's PyDev Python Console?

Tags: python, eclipse, performance

Can anyone help me understand why the PyDev Console in Eclipse is slower than the Eclipse console?

Example:

I run the following code in the PyDev console:

```
import time
start = time.time()
a = range(100000)
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i*2)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

[image: PyDev]

The same code running in the Eclipse console:

[image: Eclipse]

There is quite a big difference in the time needed to run the code. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse console is an overlay to pure system terminal and doesn't contain Java overhead for parsing a Python Console output. Try to do something similar after going to python interactive mode in system terminal (simply type `python` -> Enter). Probably you will see time somewhere in between your Console and PyDev Console time. Generally, your code will run in a terminal alike environment so don't bother that your PyDev Console is slow.

Comment: So you are saying that the time displayed in the console (in my example 0.014 seconds) is the correct time? Just making sure since I am working on code that needs to run real-time, meaning in about 25 milliseconds.

Comment: Yes. Console time is, more or less, real-time of running your code. You can try to open your system terminal/console and run your script from there. Run time should be about the same.